# dart language: Map<Object,String> how to add new pair?

Tags: dictionary, dart

Given:

```
Map<WebSocket,String> mListUser;
mListUser= new  Map<WebSocket,String>();
```

From what i understood now to add a new element i should just do:

```
mListUser[socket]="string";
```

instead im getting:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the error I'd say `mListUser` is a `List`, not a `Map`. Is this the original, real code that you copied?

Comment: i was using before a list and forgot to change the name, am defenetly using a map. As Gero as shown, i think im doing it right way, i guess there is something wrong in the object i use as a key, which by the way is the same Websocket i get from the onConnection on the Chathandler class (source here https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch05.html)

Comment: Well, without any further info, I can just stubbornly reiterate: The error message says that somewhere, you are trying to assign a String to a variable or parameter named "index", which has to be an integer. If this is the real code, this error may not even relate to the map at all.

Answer (score 36):

Maybe it helps

```
final test = Map<String, int>();
test.putIfAbsent('58', () => 56);
```

if key doesn't exist, it will be putted into map.

Comment: I am using a `Map<DateTime, Lis<Event>>' (Event is a random class). Every time I add a new pair, the key (DateTime) is correctly added, but the list is replaced in all keys. Any help? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it helps.

```
Map<Object,String> map1= new Map<Object,String>();
Collections c = new Collections(); //some random class

map1[new Collections()]="arg1";
map1[c]="arg2";

map1.forEach((k,v)=>print("out: $k $v"));
print(map1[c]);
```

gets me this output:

```
out: Instance of 'Collections' arg2
out: Instance of 'Collections' arg1
arg2
```

Comment: I found the problem or identify it. Since im using 'dart:io'; instead of import 'dart:html'; is seems that in the first, WebSocket is an abstract class and trying to use it as a key just doen't work, at least in that way. Note that in a project with 'dart:html'; everything works as expected as suggested above by Gero