# Adding Maps inside Map<dynamic, dynamic> Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I sit **6 Hours** trying to add
`Map<dynamic, dynamic>` **Contains** `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` **inside Another** `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

How to add Map like this:

```
{
    map1:{
          map1_key1: map1_val1
          map1_key2: map1_val2
          map1_2:{
                  map1_3:{
                           map3_key1: map3_val1
                           map3_key1: map3_val2
                         }
                  map2_key1: map2_val1
                  map2_key1: map2_val2
                 }

          map1_key3: map1_val3
         }
}
```

repeatedly inside map called `masterMap` , and access every key/value inside it like any other map ?

- i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291203/continuously-add-data-to-map)
- i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175515/dart-language-mapobject-string-how-to-add-new-pair)
- i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651673/converting-string-to-map-in-dart)
- i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200560/combine-merge-multiple-maps-into-1-map/45200659)

  - tried addAll() function gives me error called on null..
  - tried addEntries() function gives me

    ```
    The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>>'
    ```

nothing work , i need help this is very bad and stupid thing , why there is no simple function to merge all map key/value with another one , that simple ?!

**Update:**
my code:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> theSnapShot;
theSnapShot = {
  'map1': {
          '-LyUAD8B0LpKZ-5-cRn-': {
                   'CoordsMap': [null, {'FirstCoords': '30.088,31.279',}]
                                  }
          }
             };
Map<dynamic, dynamic> masterMap;
masterMap.addAll(Map.from(theSnapShot['map1']));
```

output:

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addAll()' was called on null.
```

Comment: can you please show your current code?

Comment: i provided sample code .. i need to add this map under some key to list of maps

Comment: you mean that you have map like first code snippet and you need to add `theSnapShot ` to that map right?

Comment: @Blasanka True ...

Answer (score 3):

it's simple
you have two choices right here, 1st : to define key then assign value to it

```
Map someThing = {
    "someThing2":{
      'key1': 'val1',
      'key2': 'val2',
      'key3': {},
    }
  };
// {someThing2: {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: {}}}
someThing['someThing2']['key3'] = {
    'someThing3': {
          'key4': 'val4',
        },
  };
// {someThing2: {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: {someThing3: {key4: val4}}}}
```

2nd option is to add the key and the value, just like the following

```
Map someThing = {
    "someThing2":{
      'key1': 'val1',
      'key2': 'val2',
    }
  };

someThing['someThing2'].putIfAbsent('key4', () => {
    'someThing3': {
          'key4': 'val4',
        },
  });
// {someThing2: {key1: val1, key2: val2, key4: {someThing3: {key4: val4}}}}
```

Comment: i don't know someThing map values , so i just define it as Map someThing; , and when i try putIfAbsent it gives me error was called on null ..

Comment: did you try `Map someThing = {};` `someThing.putIfAbsent('key4', () => {
    'someThing3': {
          'key4': 'val4',
        },
  });`

Comment: yes, and added it in the initState function and tried to rebuild the app , same problem !!

Answer (score 1):

Your out put `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addAll()' was called on null.` because of you havent initalized `masterMap`, just do this:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> masterMap = {};
```

I dont know it is solved your problem or not, Since, you said you dont know the key, I think below is what you are looking for:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> theSnapShot;
theSnapShot = {
  'map1': {
      '-LyUAD8B0LpKZ-5-cRn-': {
         'CoordsMap': [null, {'FirstCoords': '30.088,31.279',}]
      }
   }
};
Map<dynamic, dynamic> masterMap = Map.from(theSnapShot);
theSnapShot.forEach((key, value) {
    masterMap.addAll(theSnapShot[key]);
});

print(masterMap);

//output
//{map1: {-LyUAD8B0LpKZ-5-cRn-: {CoordsMap: [null, {FirstCoords: 30.088,31.279}]}}, -LyUAD8B0LpKZ-5-cRn-: {CoordsMap: [null, {FirstCoords: 30.088,31.279}]}}
```

Here is a simple example that I have created in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/40080ff2402be5f845080d11c39ca1da).

Comment: @Almodoen let me know if this not solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

This a working version of your code

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> theSnapShot;
theSnapShot = {
  'map1': {
          '-LyUAD8B0LpKZ-5-cRn-': {
                   'CoordsMap': [null, {'FirstCoords': '30.088,31.279',}]
                                  }
          }
             };
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> masterMap = theSnapShot;
  masterMap.addAll(theSnapShot["map1"]);
  print(masterMap);
```

basically it initializes the `masterMap` with the `theSnapShot` map and it appends the `map1` entry to the `masterMap`. So the `masterMap` will look like at the end

```
{
    "map1": {
      "-LyUAD8B0LpKZ-5-cRn-": {"CoordsMap": [null, {"FirstCoords": "30.088,31.279"}]}},

    "-LyUAD8B0LpKZ-5-cRn-": {"CoordsMap": [null, {"FirstCoords": "30.088,31.279"}]}}
```

is this your desired output?

Comment: good you added ["map1"] instead of [map1] but it's the same for my problem , i have very complex maps in the snapshot , but i provided sample , but it doesn't work , i didn't initializes the masterMap with the theSnapShot map , because i don't know the theSnapShot values , it's a Future from firebase realtime-database , i just define masterMap like this 
Map<dynamic, dynamic> masterMap;
addAll function doesn't work here ..

Comment: so you have incoming data from firebase database and you want to insert them inside your masterMap?

Comment: not exactly , but yes something like you said , but i make for loop on the received data to extract CoordsMap map from every map1 and add it to the masterMap .. , that gives me Map called masterMap containing CoordsMap's Maps , to access it using forEach or someting similar